# Problema al restaurar una bd en sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Buen día, mi problema es este, acabo de descargarme la versión 2008 de sql server y quiero restaurar una bd de más de 5gb, pero me sale un error que estoy horas intentando solucionar y me está volviendo loco, quisiera saber si en la versión gratuita que te da microsoft puedo restaurar esa data, ya que un amigo me dijo que sólo puedo restaurar máximo 1GB y no los 5GB que tengo, y también si por ahí puedo hacerlo con otro gestor de bd que me permita tal volumen de data. Ahora tengo también otro problema que me acaba de surgir, es por una ip de un servidor local y mejor les muestro la imagen para que me puedan ayudar. Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No parece ser problema de tamaño, sino que simplemente de versiones del motor de base de datos. La base de datos de la cuál hiciste el backup es de la versión SQL Server 2008 R2, y la estás tratando de restaurar en un motor de base de datos que está en la versión SQL Server 2008

Comment: Genera un script que sea compatible para SQL Server 2008. En la red hay bastante informacion incluyendo tutoriales sobre el tema.

Comment: ok, el problema del tamaño fue con el sql server management studio 2017, y ahora el otro problema es con el sql 2008, pero voy a volver a instalar el sql, gracias.

Comment: saben si puedo restaurar una bd de más de 5gb?

Answer (score 0):

buen dìa con todos, era lo que me esperaba, logré instalar el sql 2008 r2 pero al parecer los 5gb que tengo es mucha data para mi versión express, pero hay algo que no entiendo, en la versión express dice que su capacidad es alrededor de 10gb pero bueno, claro está en este pantallazo, alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto para poder restaurar mi bd que es con un fin educativo, o si es que la única forma es de tener el sql licenciado. Gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

El problema es bastante claro. Estás restaurando una base de datos de la versión 2008 R2 a una instancia 2008. No se pueden restaurar bases de datos a versiones anteriores.

La única opción es actualizar la instancia a una versión más actual. Si es para un ambiente de desarrollo, puedes descargar e instalar de forma gratuita la edición Developer creando una cuenta de [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/), sí es para algo productivo, las versiones más recientes de SQL Server permiten hasta 10GB por base de datos en [su edición Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) que es gratuita.

Comment: Mas que una respuesta es un comentario, un comentario que ya le colocaron. Y si tiene opciones, y es la de generar un script con compatibilidad a SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Generar un script es muy distinto a crear un respaldo. Sí se puede generar un script compatible con una versión anterior, pero no se puede generar un respaldo para una versión anterior.

Comment: Estas en lo correcto, no se puede generar un respaldo para una version anterior. Pero para lo que el OP necesita no es necesario un respaldo. El solo quiera pasar de una base de datos a otra. El supuso hacer un backup pero lo detuvo las versiones. En si. si puede generar script.

Comment: Lee de nuevo, quiere restaurar 5GB de datos. Eso no los genera un script.

Comment: Si los genera. E incluso me ha tocado hacerlo con data de mas de 5gb. Lo quieres hacer a mano: genera el script del esquema. aparte genera los script de aquellas tablas que solo son tipos o estados, luego las tablas que tienen poco datos y dejar las mas pesadas de ultimo. A todo esto se debe desactivar las restricciones de llaves. Todo esto se tuvo que fragcionar ya que el sql management no puede cargar registros tan grande. No creo que sea el primero que lo haga ni el ultimo. es tedioso? si.

Comment: E incluso algunas veces no ha tocada solo generar script del esquema y valores iniciales y el resto de datos se pasa con un programita de consola, ¿esto es inasectable? pues si. y ha veces toco hacerlo y mas si tu cliente no sabe nada de tecnologia. El problema del OP es si solo le dieron el archivo back.

Comment: Estás hablando de copiar una base de datos por medio de la generación de scripts. Eso es lento y tampoco es la forma óptima de hacerlo. Es mucho mejor hacerlo con SSIS o algún otro sistema que permita cargar datos en paralelo. De cualquier forma, sería mucho mejor actualizar a una versión que tenga menos de 10 años de existencia y que no vaya a perder el soporte este año.

Comment: Hablo de copiar una base de datos por medio de la generación de scripts cuando el cliente te deja con las manos atajas.